# What is the benefit of upgrading Flight Management System to version UNS-1Ew?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, avionics

I am working in a private airlines. We have some Dash-8 Q400 aircraft in our fleet. Recently a SB has been issued telling us to upgrade the Flight Management System from  UNS-1E to UNS-1Ew.

Can anyone explain what are the advantages for upgrading the Flight Management System from UNS-1E to UNS-1Ew?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my understanding of the update. As others I believe your primary source should be your OEM.

**Main purpose: Ability to use SBAS procedures and navigation**

The purpose of moving from UNS-1E to UNS-1Ew is getting the [SBAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNSS_augmentation) capability. From the UNS-1Ew manual:

> The new “W” series of Universal Avionics Flight Management systems
>   incorporate the Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS) Space Based
>   Augmentation System (SBAS) known in North America as the Wide Area
>   Augmentation System (WAAS). Other SBAS systems in the world will also
>   be incorporated.

**SBAS details**

SBAS means using WAAS, EGNOS and other GNSS augmentation systems. SBAS in short provides for correction of GNSS radio signal propagation errors in a limited area. This increases pseudo-ranging accuracy and positioning precision.

<sup>SBAS (space-based) is opposed to GBAS (ground-based) where correction broadcasting stations are on the ground, like the [DGPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_GPS), a surveying GBAS with a positioning precision up to 10 cm.</sup>

EGNOS measuring network (SBAS for Europe area):

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Geostationary_Navigation_Overlay_Service)</sup>

---

**Additional benefits of the update**

From [UASC documentation](https://www.uasc.com/docs/default-source/documents/brochures/uasc_nextgen_solutions_brochure.pdf?sfvrsn=6):

> What else you get with an SBAS-FMS upgrade:
>
> •  Performance-Based Navigation (PBN) including Precision-Area
>   Navigation (P-RNAV) compliance and Required Navigation
>   Performance/Area Navigation (RNP/RNAV) up to 0.3 NM approach accuracy
>
> • WAAS LPV / EGNOS APV, LNAV approaches
>
> • Mode S Enhanced Surveillance support
>
> •  Accurate SBAS-GPS information provided to the onboard Terrain
>   Awareness and Warning System/Enhanced Ground Proximity Warning System
>   (TAWS/EGPWS) and Traffic Collision Avoidance System (TCAS)
>
> •  Large database capacity for worldwide navigation databases

You can read ["The Benefits of SBAS"](https://www.uasc.com/home/nextgentechnologies/improvesafetywithsbas-fms) on UASC site.

And if you need more information the [UNS-1Ew manual](http://www.gta.igs.net/~kiddbatt/DOCS/unsbs/1000_Training_Manual_may2010.pdf) is also available.

Comment: Don't forget that ADS-B requires a WAAS capable receiver.